# Mystery bug in console (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

There is a script that changes the background color of all tags in WordPress.

Tried to put different names in querySelectorAll nothing helps =(

This script works fine, but for some reason the console shows this:
[image]
[image]

**I don’t understand where the error is,
the script works fine, but there is an error in the console.**

```js
let tags_links = document.querySelectorAll('.tag-cloud-link');  

function xex2(){
    
let colors = 
['#1E90FF', '#CD5C5C', '#BC8F8F', '#B22222', '#5F9EA0', '#9932CC', '#4682B4',  
'#1E90FF', '#7B68EE', '#9400D3', '#6A5ACD', '#C71585', '#4682B4', '#FF7F50', 
'#C71585', '#FF1493', '#778899',  '#9370DB', '#D2691E', '#708090', '#A0522D', '#3CB371'];

for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) { 
tags_links[i].style.background = colors[i % colors.length];
}

}

xex2();
```

```css
body{
display:grid;                                            
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(15%, 25%)); 
grid-template-areas:     
 "Tags     Tags     Tags     Tags" ;
}

.Tags_Main_Block{
grid-area: Tags;
font-family:arial;  
padding:1vw;
line-height: 1.5;
border-top: 2px solid rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
}

.opase{ 
margin-bottom:40px;
}

.tag-titles{
margin-top:30px;
font-size:35px;
color:#00BFFF;  
padding-left:15px;
text-align:center;
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.tag-cloud-link{
display: inline-block;
margin-top:15px;
margin-left:15px;   
background: #1E90FF;
padding:5px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:  10px;
border-radius:10px;
color:white ;
}
```

```html
<article class="Tags_Main_Block"> 
<p class="tag-titles">TAGS:</p>
<div class="opase">

<?php 
$myTags = wp_tag_cloud(  
['format' => 'array',
'echo' => false,
'smallest'  => 14,
'largest'   => 14,
'unit'      => 'pt',
'number'    => 0,
'separator' => "",
'orderby'   => 'name',
'order'     => 'ASC',
'exclude'   => null,
'include'   => null,
'link'      => 'view',
'taxonomy'  => 'post_tag',
'topic_count_text_callback' => 'default_topic_count_text',
]); 

asort($myTags);
foreach($myTags as $tag) {
echo $tag;
}

?>

</div>
</article>
```

Comment: Why are you going from 0 to 200? You clearly don't have 200 of those items in the page.

Comment: The error is telling you that `tag_links[i]` is `undefined`; have you inspected your elements to ensure the class is being applied?

Comment: they may appear in the future, so I made it ahead of time

Comment: You are right. at the moment I have 44 elements. But what if we add element 45? Should I manually change the value in the code from 44 to 45? How to make value equal to number of tag elements

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < tag_links.length; i++) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: Aioros, thank you very much. length is an array method, isn't it? querySelectorAll convert elements to array?

Comment: Almost. [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and not an array, but like an array that class has a [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/length) property.

Answer (score 1):

`let tags_links = document.querySelectorAll('.tag-cloud-link');`

, is out of scope of xex2.